# Can we have Springboot jar + NextJs running on same port as a packaged Jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, next.js

Ideally NextJs code runs on a different port 3000. Can we have NextJS code clubbed in Springboot executable Jar /WAR (embedded Tomcat) which runs on default port 8080, and make the clubbed application jar/war run on single port?

Just want to highlight, React JS can be clubbed with Springboot , whereas NextJS I am no sure.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is written in Javascript, Spring Boot is written in Java, they cannot be run together. However, after you run them in different ports, you can use a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx) to stick them together under the same port but different endpoints (for example map Next.js to / and Spring Boot to /api)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can !

Check the answer over here:

[How do I serve the NextJs application from spring boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333551/how-do-i-serve-the-nextjs-application-from-spring-boot-application)

you need to modify the api link inside the nextjs (frontend)
from http://xxxxx to /xxx,